# NullPointerException when Inflating a WebView in Android

Tags: android, layout, webview, nullpointerexception, inflate

I'm getting this bizarre error trying to inflate a webview in one of my layouts

```
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at com.philly.prosportsframework.fragments.HomeLauncherFragment.buildView(HomeLauncherFragment.java:317)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at com.philly.prosportsframework.fragments.HomeLauncherFragment$LauncherListAdapter.getView(HomeLauncherFragment.java:299)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1156)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1848)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-15 10:49:30.790: E/AndroidRuntime(18749):    at c
11-15 10:49:30.850: D/dalvikvm(18749): GC_CONCURRENT freed 314K, 6% free 7612K/8071K, paused 13ms+4ms, total 51ms
11-15 10:49:30.850: E/System(18749): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
11-15 10:49:30.850: E/System(18749): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-15 10:49:30.850: E/System(18749):    at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.destroyJava(WebViewClassic.java:2087)
11-15 10:49:30.850: E/System(18749):    at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.destroy(WebViewClassic.java:2072)
11-15 10:49:30.850: E/System(18749):    at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.finalize(WebViewClassic.java:4126)
11-15 10:49:30.850: E/System(18749):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:186)
11-15 10:49:30.850: E/System(18749):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:169)
11-15 10:49:30.850: E/System(18749):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

The line of code that's referenced in the trace is:

```
v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_launcher_item, null);
```

and the layout file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


           <WebView
        android:id="@+id/photo" 
        android:layout_width="330dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"        
        android:background="@drawable/thumb"/>

    <TextView   
        android:id="@+id/title" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
        android:layout_above="@+id/byline"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_marginTop="20px"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="25px"
        android:lines="2"
        android:background="#dd000000"/>                

    <TextView   
        android:id="@+id/byline"    
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/photo"
        android:textColor="#ff565656"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:background="#dd000000"/>   
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas would be helpful.  I'm using a Xoom running Android 4.1.1 to test.

Comment: Hard to see - What's parent?

Comment: Do you actually have the `res/drawable/thumb.png` resource?

Comment: Do you have the internet permission in your Manifest ? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: @JeffG I don't think it would cause an InflateException

Comment: its not just inflate but even nullpointer..... i am in a doubt.... What's parent as @j.carlosNavea asked

Comment: fiddler, you nailed it.  thumb.png didn't exist in the project.  Usually, eclipse tells me when a drawable is missing, but for some reason in this case, it doesn't.  If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: oops i didnt face this kinda situation... even if the drawable is absent the eclipse started running without giving any error!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `res/drawable/thumb.png` is probably missing. You need to add it or change the reference to an existing drawable resource.

The XML layout validator is sometimes buggy. Don't trust him ;)